# NearbyApi but AppMetaData and AppIdentifier deprecated

Tags: android, google-nearby

I just tried to use the NearBy Api from Google but there is a problem :
this API uses AppMetaData and AppIdentifier which are deprecated.

What should I do ? do not care about ?

thx

[NearBy Api](https://developers.google.com/nearby/connections/android/get-started)

[AppMetadata](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/nearby/connection/AppMetadata)